# How does bcp utill exactly work?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Could somebody explain me how does bcp utill exactly work?

If i understand it correct, it sends some data package to the SQL Server, and waits some response, which means that uploading has completed. If there is not such response from server during period of time which is longer than bcp connection timeout, it should fail with timeout exception.

But what we would see, if bcp connection timeout = 0 and during sending response from a server some network errors have occurred? Is it possible that bcp uploading just hanged in such case?

Thanks